Transitioning from Polygon Mumbai to Avalanche Fuji: Seeking USDT Asset ID for Integration
I’m currently integrating USDC and USDT into an Ethereum mainnet environment using Fireblocks. Fireblocks provides a list of supported asset IDs through their API endpoint
List all assets and assets types supported by Fireblocks.
Initially, for testing purposes, we were utilizing the Polygon Mumbai network with the following asset IDs:

MATIC_POLYGON_MUMBAI for USDC
USDT_POLYGON_TEST_MUMBAI_ZU3P for USDT

However, since Polygon Mumbai is deprecated, I’m considering transitioning to Avalanche Fuji. I’ve found an asset ID for USDC (AVAXTEST), but I’m uncertain if there’s a supported asset ID for USDT on the Avalanche network.
Could someone confirm if there’s a supported asset ID for USDT on Avalanche Fuji, or suggest an alternative approach for integrating USDT in an Ethereum mainnet environment with Fireblocks? Thank you.
